# Getting my email that i migrated with

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I seem to have forgotten my email that i got my microsoft account with and minecraft help needs my transaction id that might been deleted by gmail (the 30 day thing) so minecraft support did nothing and my launcher accounts json doesnt show the information about that account its just empty. Please someone help me I really want to get into my minecraft account again.
PS: i cant find launcher_profiles.json.backup and authenticationDatabase with the username field.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation, as it is hard to read your question. On the other hand, we might not be able to help you anyway, as this is a question for Microsoft support.

Comment: Are you sure your mail is gone? Gmail doesn't delete mails automatically, not in 30 days, nor ever. If you check your mail on the Android app, it may only show the last 30 days, but the rest are still there too. Unless, of course, you decided to delete it yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have that information, I do not think you can recover your Minecraft account.

Comment: ah thanks.
I didn't know that